# How to a create a slate roof tile with rough edges?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I'm looking for the best way to achieve a slate roof tile effect in cycles like the attached photo. I'm not looking to create a roof like this just a single panel/tile.

To create the rough edges, I've tried subdividing a plane, selecting the outer faces, and applying a Voronoi texture displacement modifier, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere close!

My attempt so far:
[image: my attempt so far]

What I'm looking to achieve!
[image: slate tile]

Comment: Are you open to sculpting the detail?

Comment: you could fake it with a photo but I guess you want real displacement...  ;)

Comment: Yeah I was ideally hoping for displacement on the model without sculpting.

Comment: I've been staring at your reference for a while and I'm pretty sure it's a render to begin with x)  Looks like one tile repeated and just flipped around sometimes.

Comment: @AllenSimpson  Well spotted! It repeats! Or... they could be synthetic  real-world slates..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would solve the problem with microdisplacement.  I think you're in the ballpark.

My model is a cube that I scaled down on the Z axis and gave some loop cuts to.

[image]

Then I grabbed the top and bottom outer edge (in edge select mode) and beveled with a couple divisions.

[image]

And that's it, slap some adaptive subdivision on there and head to the node editor.  Set your object's material to Displacement and Bump.

[image]

In the shader editor, you can use a *Vector Math* node to multiply the object coordinates by itself a couple of times and then run that output through a *Gradient Texture* set to *Spherical* to generate this interesting output.

[image]

You can use a *Color Ramp* here to define the cutoff between the jagged edge and the smooth plane.  For whatever reason I used an *Invert* node here, but you can just flip the *Color Ramp* around.

[image]

This is the scale input of your *Displacement* node.  Multiply it by a value that makes sense(0.04?), plug it in, and put all of this aside except for the *Displacement* node.

[image]

Now grab some fresh coordinates and start with a Voronoi texture as you first suspected.  I've used a *Mapping* node to squish it on the Z axis which I think is more accurate to the reference.  If you plug this into the height input, and plug the *Displacement* node into the *Material Output* we get immediate results because we've already set up our scale.

[image]

With some adjustment to the *Color Ramp* from before, the scale of the texture, and the Midlevel of the *Displacement* node, maybe this is enough for what you need.

**The thing to know to actually use this** is that since we're using *Object Coordinates* if you need to scale the object and *Apply Scale*, you have to go into the shader editor and make an inverse change to the *Mapping* nodes.  This is kind of an annoyance and a failing on my end because I gave up on making this work with generated coordinates.

For example, if you've scaled this model on the X axis, you also need to decrease the scale of the X axis on the bottom *Mapping* node.  Here's a view of how our change in the *Mapping* node is represented in rendered view.  (This does get fiddly and again I apologize.)

[image]

[image]

You can, of course, go much further than this.

...And I have...

Around here you start getting some good results.

[image]

Just kidding, here's the blend file.

[image]

This is what this crazy graph looks like set to Bump Only.

[image]

And here's a showcase with displacement and RTX ON.

[image]

Every instance of the object is slightly different.

[image]

Microtexture in the Bump layer.

[image]

Comment: "You can, of course, go much further than this ...And I have..." Well played sir :))

Comment: Very, very, nice

Comment: Thanks so much for this it is incredibly helpful, I really appreciate it :). I'm having a bit of trouble when using a rectangle shape. In your example, you used a square which works great when using the "Spherical" option on the gradient texture but not so great with a rectangle. I tried to use the pointiness from the Geometry instead but didn't really have any luck. Didn't know if you had any further ideas? I realise I was using a square in my blender example photo, I was just trying out to see what I could achieve but in real life, they are usually rectangular in shape.

Comment: No problem!  This question made me look at some of my old files and it turns out I needed this as well.  If you mess with the X and Y scale of the bottom mapping node it should move the edges around, and the top mapping node can be used as a quick handle for the other texture scales.